# Bot checking if the name of ctx.channel is in a given list discord.py

Tags: string, events, discord.py, bots

I have made the code below:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
  if '?' in ctx.content and ctx.author != client.user.id and ['cmd', 'bot', 'command'] in ctx.channel.name:

    print(f'runned by {ctx.author}')

    await ctx.channel.send('yup definently worked')
```

The problem is that the bot won't check the list since the `['cmd', 'bot', 'command']` requires a `string` as the left operand, and not a `list`.

Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not compare it the other way around?

```py
if ctx.channel.name in ['cmd', 'bot', 'command']
```

EDIT:

```py
if any(ctx.channel.name in ['cmd', 'bot', 'command']
```

*PS: `on_message` doesn't take `ctx` as an argument, it takes `message`*

Comment: hmm I wish it worked. I just tried, although this time it doesnt even give me any errors. I'll set up some error handling, brb

Comment: Why should there be an error in the first place? Seems like a logic problem to me

Comment: I was thinking the same, but it doesn't even respond with `if ctx.channel.name in ['cmd', 'bot', 'command']`. I would think it's because the channel itself isn't called "bot" in this case. It works like this: `'bot' in message.channel.name`, but when it comes to the whole list, it simply ignores it